# Net Core IOptions<AppSettings> use

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've followed the IOptions pattern in an MVC project and can inject my appsettings into my Controller:

```
public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings) {
    _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
}
```

I have a bunch of other classes that are instantiated from HomeController - can I directly inject  into these as well or do I have to pass in _appSettings on each class instantiation?

Ideally all my classes would inject  in the constructor, like the Controller.

Comment: Yes; you can use your own classes with dependency injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency injection is an all or nothing affair. If you're going to use DI, then you *always* use DI and virtually never manually new up anything (except basic classes like entities with no dependencies). In other words, if your controller is instantiating things that take dependencies, those things should be registered in the service collection and injected into the controller instead. For example, assuming you're doing something like:

```
public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
}

public IActionResult Foo()
{
    var service = new FooService(_appSettings);

    // do something
}
```

Then, you should add in your `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<FooService>();
```

And in your controller, you should instead be doing:

```
public HomeController(FooService fooService)
{
    _fooService = fooService
}
```

The service collection will take care of injecting your options into the service, since the service itself has a dependency on that.

Comment: Apologies, I don't see how other classes will be able to get the injected code without passing _appSettings to each class constructor?

Comment: The service provider takes care of injection of all dependencies, all the way down the dependency chain.

Comment: I mean you class constructors must take the requisite dependencies as params, of course, but you don't have to worry about filling those in yourself.

Comment: What happens if you want to pass in something else in the Constructors:

Comment: If you can register it in the service collection, you can pass it to the constructor. There is no limit, though a class with too many dependencies is likely breaking the single responsibility principle. The one exception is primitive types like strings, because those cannot be registered as sevices, but you can use the provider action overload, to explicitly state how a service should be instantiated, such as by passing some sort of string. All of this is in the docs.

Comment: Oops seems like I didn't complete my previous reply and posted it in error - thanks anyway